# JQuery rotate + animation in IE

Tags: jquery, rotation, jquery-animate

I want to rotate and enlarge a picture on hover (smoothly). I'm using JqueryRotate to rotate the picture and .animate() for the enlargement.
I got the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jQueryRotateCompressed.2.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).rotate({animateTo:30})
        $(this).stop().animate({width:'90px',height:'90px'}, 500 );



    },
    function(){
        $(this).rotate({animateTo:0})
        $(this).stop().animate({width:'34px',height:'34px'}, 500);


}); 
});
</script>
```

-----> my head code

```
<body>
<img id="test" src="images/facebook.png" />
</body>
```

Now this works perfect in Firefox, Chrome and Safari... But ofcourse IE is a pita.
I'm testing on IE8 right now and it does rotate but it will not enlarge for some reason.. if I test the function withouth the rotation it enlarges just fine... so it's the combination of the 2 that does not work in IE8. Does anybody know a solution? thx

Comment: If you are animating a div which contains the image, try setting the image width/height to 100% in css so that it fits the div.

Comment: That is not the issue, it works fine in all browsers but in IE it just rotates, but it does not enlarge...

check out my working example so you know what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/Xn2ep/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of the plugin that you are using, i.e 2.2 of jQuery rotate has bugs with IE8.

Please try out the 3.0 version of the plugin which works[(click here to download)](https://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate3.js) but is buggy when used together with resizing the image.

This is due to the fact that the plugin places the image in a canvas then rotates the latter. When you try to increase the size of the image, it in fact increases the size of the canvas, therefore increasing the area where `.hover()` function is applicable.

Test it on your own website to see the aliens and UFOs on IE8.

**My recommendation:** Don't resize the image if you want to rotate it. These two are like cats and dogs.

Comment: thx for the comment. I just tested it in IE8 and I get a buggy animation :). It is so weird that a simple thing like this is not able to work in IE. I guess I'll have to create an other animation.